# User input validation agains the database with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Iam working on one application and right now I stuck in this issue: I have registered user and I need a function to change his password. The server side which is in php works great. But when user is changing the password I need to check his input for "old password" in the form with the database and if it is not same I would like to have some java script alert.
Hope it is clear, my code is here

My idea is to create php variable $oldpsw. Then put the variable to java script  var = oldpsw. Than get user input through document.getElementById(oldpsw).value And than compare these two variables. Any suggestions?
BTW I am beginner :)

This is php server side which woks perfect

```
        $_SESSION['user_id'];
        include('confirmations.php');
        require_once('Db.php');
        Db::connect( 'localhost', 'chovejslepici_db','root', 'root');
        $oldpsw=Db::querySingle('
                                    SELECT psw
                                    FROM user
                                    WHERE user_id = ?
                                    ',$_SESSION['user_id']);


        if($_POST['oldpsw']==$oldpsw)
                    {
                        Db::query('
                               UPDATE user
                               SET psw= ?
                               WHERE user_id = ?
                               ',$_POST['newpsw'], $_SESSION['user_id']);

                    }
```

Here is HTML part

```
<form action="pswchange.php" method="post" class="rename">
<h3 class="headline pt">Change psi</h3>
<label class="headline" for="oldpsw">Old Psw <input class="center" value="<?php echo $oldpsw ?>" type="password" name="oldpsw" id="oldpsw" placeholder="Staré heslo"></label>
<label class="headline" for="newpsw">New Psw <input class="center" type="password" name="newpsw" id="newpsw" placeholder="Nové heslo"></label>
<button class="rename-button" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" id="submit">Změnit heslo</button>
</form>
```

And try to validate with this JS script

```
var oldpsw = "<?php echo $oldpsw ?>" ;
    var formpsw = document.getElementById("oldpsw").value;


    function myFunction() {
    if (formpsw!=oldpsw) {
        alert("Wrong Old Password try again.");
    }
    else{
        alert("Password successfully changed!");
    }

}
```

Right now I have got everytime this alert("Wrong Old Password try again."); Don't know why.

Comment: What is the ouput of `<?php echo $oldpsw ?>` exactly? Is it returning the `id` of an `input` element?

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Don't do the comparison in JS on the client side, or the client can simply ignore it. Do the comparison in PHP on the server side.

Comment: Sorry forgot to explain in $oldpsw I have got stored psw from database. Also thanks for suggestions about password storing

Comment: Please note that you should also probably hash the password. As was said before, it is really a bad idea to return the password from DB to the client. A more robust and secured design would be to return something like status 401 as a response and then react in client accordingly. As @AlexHowansky said, do it on the server side, only react on the client.